# Как с помощью fetch распарсить картинку в base64 асинхронно?

Tags: javascript, асинхронность, base64, fetch, async-await

есть такая функция и она работает )

```
  function toDataURL(url, callback) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function() {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = function() {
            callback(reader.result);
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
        };
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.send();
    }
```

но я пишу асинхронный код

```js
let url = 'https://somethingoffreedom.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Kelingking-beach-Nusa-Penida-Bali-travel-tips.jpg';


async function setBaseImg () {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data     = await response.blod();
  let   reader   = await new FileReader();
  
  
  await document.querySelectorAll('img')[0].setAttribute('src', reader.readAsDataURL(data) )
}


setBaseImg();
```

```html
<img src="" alt="">
```

но он не работает , как мне его оживить что бы в **src** загрузилось *base64*
или если это не возможно то как я могу применит *асинхронно* функцию  **toDataURL** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) если только методы с callback, поэтому часть с

```
let reader = await new FileReader();
...
, reader.readAsDataURL(...)
```

не может работать.

Для решения нужно либо оставить подход с callback какой и был:

```js
let url = 'https://somethingoffreedom.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Kelingking-beach-Nusa-Penida-Bali-travel-tips.jpg';

async function setBaseImg() {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.blob();

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('img')[0].setAttribute('src', reader.result)
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(data);
}


setBaseImg();
```

---

Либо обернуть работу с callback в функцию возвращающую Promise

```
let url = 'https://somethingoffreedom.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Kelingking-beach-Nusa-Penida-Bali-travel-tips.jpg';

function readAsync(data) {
    return new Promise(r=>{
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function() {
          r(reader.result)
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(data);        
    });
}

async function setBaseImg() {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.blob();
  const dataUrl = await readAsync(data);

  document.querySelectorAll('img')[0].setAttribute('src', dataUrl);
}

setBaseImg();
```

---

Кроме того, **НЕ НУЖНО везде** добавлять `await`, их нужно добавлять только там, где надо.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let url =
  "https://somethingoffreedom.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Kelingking-beach-Nusa-Penida-Bali-travel-tips.jpg";


function setBase64ToImage(result) {
  const element = document.querySelector("img");
  element.setAttribute('src', result);
  console.log(element);
}

async function loadImg() {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.blob();

  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    setBase64ToImage(reader.result)
  }

  reader.readAsDataURL(data);
}

loadImg();
```

```html
<img src="" alt="Image"/>
```